# DNS A Record and balancing

Tags: dns, rotation, record

I have classical DNS Record type A, I have 4 of them and each one is redirecting to different IP, but for some reason people ping much more often one of them instead all of them.

I have also this problem if I ping dns.mydomain.com I ping always only 1 of the IPs in the rotation but on my second 4G connection I ping every 5 minutes different IP, so on my 4G connection the balancing works.

Where is the problem ?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

When client gets list of IP addresses returned by DNS server, it can use its own preferred algorithm to choose the address it will use (usually it is either the first one in the list, or the the longest prefix match per [RFC3484](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt)). If you add the unkonown behavior of any DNS cache servers between the client and the authoritative name servers, you end up with unpredictable results.

- [Round-robin DNS Drawbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS#Drawbacks)
- [DNS Round Robin and Destination IP address selection](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2009/04/17/dns-round-robin-and-destination-ip-address-selection.aspx)
- [GETADDRINFO WITH ROUND ROBIN DNS AND HAPPY EYEBALLS](http://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2012/01/03/getaddrinfo-with-round-robin-dns-and-happy-eyeballs/)
- [High Availability and load balancing with round robin DNS, does it really work?](http://www.emsperformance.net/2012/08/18/high-availability-load-balancing-with-round-robin-dns/)